# phpMyAdmin import Database that is missing!

Tags: phpmyadmin

My sql database in phpMyAdmin is gone but i kept the files in the directory of xampp/mysql/data/mydatabase with extensions like .MYD .MYI .frm .opt...

the thing is when i try to open it in notepad++ to see the information they seem corrupted or damaged. Then i've tried to import these files directly to the database through phpMyAdmin, but again with no results because it's full of syntax errors...

Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back the files up (back up the entire directory structure just in case), recreate a database with the same name (destroying the files), stop mysql, replace the files, start mysql.

Make sure you keep your backup in case things go wrong!

Comment: can i go to your imagination and do that? back up damaged files?

Comment: You can only import files which have been exported. The frm (table), opt (database options), MYD and MYI files are binary files and can't be (usefully) read in Notepad++.

Comment: You can copy the frm files over the top of some other frm files to recreate your tables. You can do the same with the opt file to restore your database options. I guess the other MYD and MYI files are important too; the trick is to just create some new ones and replace them with your existing ones, problem solved.